# Force GCC to ignore certain flags?

Tags: c, bash, gcc

I am trying to find a way to get GCC to temporarily ignore -arch ppc and -arch i386 flags. Does anyone have a method for accomplishing this? I have read about ways to force flags, like writing shell scripts called GCC and putting them in your path above the real GCC, but I'm looking for the opposite. My want for accomplishing this is to potentially solve this problem:

[R-Perl Install Problems with GCC 4.0: How do you remove unnecessary -arch flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162811/r-perl-install-problems-with-gcc-4-0-how-do-you-remove-unnecessary-arch-flags)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If there is any aspect of your problem that involves the C language, I would add 'C' tag, as you'll get more 'eyes' on your problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it the same way: write a wrapper script but instead of passing all flags, go through them and remove the arch flag. This can look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
gcc ${@/-arch=i386}
```

(here maybe some fine tuning is necessary: when you have to remove multiple options introduce a help variable and make the changes step by step).

EDIT: Removed other suggestion.

Comment: How would you remove the arch flag though? Also, GCC takes multiple arch flags so appending it to the end would not discard the others.

Comment: Thanks @flolo. An tweaked form of your solution worked to remove those flags. Unfortunately I am now getting errors related to something else. ;)